# Stream an m3u8 URL to LAN

Tags: local-area-network, stream

I have a stream from the web in the form of an m3u8 file. Since everybody in the office watches the same stream, it is not effective in terms of network traffic.
How can I spread the stream among the users but using only 1 stream thread to the URL from the web and all the clients would just watch the local stream?

Comment: Something like https://github.com/Viblast/hls-proxy presumably?

Comment: Sort of, but it just hangs there `Getting playlist from  https://c201-node62-cdn.connectmedia.hu/10063/c06ca4bffac431906a2acc5333711e95/5b2a5370/index.m3u8`

Comment: When I access that URL, I just get `err` as the output. They presumably have some sort of authentication or access control in place.

Comment: VLC is capable of ingesting a stream and rebroadcasting.

Comment: VLC was the 1st option I've tried, but somehow no matter what I do, it doesn't start streaming. No error or anything, just sits there like nothing happened. :/